# Flutter: How to compare two strings inside of Material Button?

Tags: flutter, string-comparison

***ANOTHER UPDATES***

Thanks to [Shri Hari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422621/flutter-how-to-change-a-void-function-to-a-class/63422695#63422695), I was able to call the `void` function in the `class`, so I don't have to call the `void` function anymore. Thank you all again for helping me so far.

***END OF ANOTHER UPDATES***

***UPDATES***

Thank you all for helpful comments! Unfortunately, I still have issues as follows:
[image]

I wonder if this issue is related to my `void` function stated below:

```
  void _takePhoto() async {
//    final _picker = ImagePicker();
//    PickedFile pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
//    final File file = File(pickedFile.path);
    ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
        .then((File recordedImage) {
      if (recordedImage != null && recordedImage.path != null) {
        GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path, albumName: albumName)
            .then((bool success) {});
      }
    });
  }
```

Thank you all again for your time and help. I truly appreciate it.

(By the way, I made sure that I include the parenthesis for the `MaterialButton`, but it is just not shown on the screen because the stuffs inside of the `MaterialButton` are too many to show all together at once.)

***END OF UPDATES***

I have the `void` function named `_takePhoto()` and other classes. If my `String iconCode` is equal to `String 'CAMERA'`, I want to visit `_takePhoto()` while other `iconCode` visits other classes. However, I have difficult time to write functional if-else statements with strings. This is what I wrote:

```
MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        iconCode = 'CAMERA' ? _takePhoto() : Navigator.of(context.pushNamed('/$iconNAme');
        setState(() {});
      }
};
```

And this is what I see:
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: You need `==` for comparing strings on which you wish to have conditions. 
Step 2: `of(context` , you need a closing parenthesis as well `)`. 
code snippet for your reference

```
MaterialButton(onPressed: () {
              iconCode == 'CAMERA'
                  ? _takePhoto()
                  : Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/$iconNAme');
              setState(() {});
            }),
```

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(title: "test",),
        '/second': (context) => iconName(),
      },
          );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  String iconCode = 'CAMERA1';
  String iconNAme = "second";

  void _takePhoto() {
    print("take photo");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {
              iconCode == 'CAMERA'
                  ? _takePhoto()
                  : Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/$iconNAme');
              setState(() {});
            }),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class iconName extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("iconName");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **=** is an assignment operator while,
   **==** checks if two objects are equal or not i.e. in your case if two strings are equal or not. Just use iconCode **==** 'CAMERA'
2. (context) is not properly closed.
   Use: `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()`

Code

```
MaterialButton(onPressed: () {
          iconCode == 'CAMERA'
              ? _takePhoto()
              : Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/$iconNAme');
          setState(() {});
        }),
```