# Flutter: How to change a void function to a class?

Tags: flutter

I am very new to Flutter, and I am trying to make the following `void` function to a `class`:

```
void _takePhoto() async {
    ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
        .then((File recordedImage) {
      if (recordedImage != null && recordedImage.path != null) {
        GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path, albumName: albumName)
            .then((bool success) {});
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried to simply place the function inside of a class, but Flutter wants me to build a `Widget build(Buildcontext context)`. So I created a simple `container`, but because the `container` was empty with a separate `void` function, I could not call the `void` function. I do not want to make the `container` clickable to pass to the `void` function, but rather, straightly execute the `void` function as soon as the `class` is called. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call your function in initState() of the stateful widget.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _takePhoto();
  }
  
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```

This calls  _takePhoto() every time of class initialization.

Answer (score 1):

a simple class definitely need not be a empty widget in flutter

```
class PhotoClass{

 void takePhoto() async {
    ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
        .then((File recordedImage) {
      if (recordedImage != null && recordedImage.path != null) {
        GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path, albumName: albumName)
            .then((bool success) {});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

to use it just create new instance

```
PhotoClass p = PhotoClass();
//execute the function
p.takePhoto();
```